# jQuery.ajax and image data encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch an image stored at S3, via AJAX, which has been uploaded using InkFilePicker. InkFilePicker has a method called filepicker.read() which can be used to read the raw data from an image. However, it's quite limited so I want to use jQuery.ajax() instead. But it seems that they don't return exactly the same data.

The data received when using filepicker.read() looks like this when logging it to the console:

[image: Data from filepicker.read()]

When using jQuery.ajax() it looks like this:

[image: Data from jQuery.ajax()]

When using the data returned by jQuery.ajax() my other scripts seems to break (I'm extracting the EXIF data).

So, why does it look different at all? Does jQuery try to encode/decode the data somehow? Can I prevent that?

Comment: You want just asynchronously load image on DOM via AJAX?

Comment: @Max No. I just want to fetch the raw image data so I can process it (in this case, extract EXIF data).

Comment: For just getting EXIF, use the [jQuery plugin](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/)

Comment: @Max, well I couldn't make it work when the image wasn't on the same server and inserted dynamically into the DOM. Instead I use this: https://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader in combination with an ajax range request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had to add this to [override the mimetype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Handling_binary_data) for some reason...

```
$.ajax({
...
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" )
  }
...
})
```

Comment: Yes. At least it makes the rest of my scripts work without complaining about bad image data...